# How to put else condition in numpy select function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of `0-23` numbers, and I was testing numpy **select** function there. where the conditions are:

1. num <= 10
2. num > 10

choices are:

1. A
2. B

Its pretty simple approach like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(24)
cond = [
arr <= 10,
arr > 10
]
choices = ['A', 'B']
result = np.select(cond, choices)
print(result)
```

I want to know that can I put **else** condition in the **select** function, because if you look at the **2nd** condition then its basically the **else** condition. If there are multiple conditions then it can become really difficult to put all the condition in that list. Can anyone please help?

Comment: [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) accepts a third parameter, which is the `else` branch: `np.select(cond, choices, default)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html#numpy-select) has another parameter called `default` that is similar to `else` coniditon i.e. if none of the conditions are `True`, the value passed to `default` will be used, so the above condition and choice lists can be reduced to a single length lists

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(24)
cond = [arr <= 10]  #Only one condition representing if
choices = ['A']  #Only one value if condition is True
result = np.select(cond, choices, default='B')  # default as B for else part
print(result)
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B'
 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `np.select` like in @ThePyGuy's answer, or you could use `np.where`:

```
result = np.where(arr <= 10, 'A', 'B')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B' 'B']
```